# How do I continue the numeric sequence of a cloned input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#inputs').children().first().clone().appendTo('#inputs');
  $('#inputs').children().last().clone().appendTo('#inputs');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='inputs'>
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][1]">
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][2]">
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][3]">
  <br>
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][1]">
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][2]">
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][3]">
</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

The Script works properly, but the only problem is copying the `name` of the `input`. I want when I clone it to change the `[1]` into its sequence number with the `['name']` changes to `['age']`  in the second clone. I also want the `['name']` to be appended to the end of the list of `['name']`.

I thought about copying the `name` then removing last two letters and replace it by the `'+index+]'` But I wonder if that the proper way to do it.

Comment: The two new `input`s are added at the end. Did you not want the `name` to be added to the end of the `name` list before the `<br>`?

Comment: @RacilHilan yes, that to, forgot to mention it since they're two different inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a normal string operation on it. Since you know the pattern, you just need the number of inputs for the number and to stick in here there. Something like this:

```
$('#inputs').children().last().attr('name', `input['name'][${$('#inputs').children().length}`);
```

Since there are now 4 (including the new one), length will give you `4` so you'll end up setting the name to `input['name'][4]`. Subsequent will give you 5, 6, and so on.

If you need to dynamically grab the name and just need to update the number, you can just find and replace the number part (since you know it'll always be `[1]`):

```
const $last = $('#inputs').children().last();
$last.attr('name', $last.attr('name').replace('[1]', `[${$('#inputs').children().length}]`));
```

With this approach, it'll use the current name, and just replace the `[1]` bit with the new number, so you'll get `[4]` in there first (so `input['name'][4]` and `input['age'][4]`, then `[5]` and so on.

Comment: But How can i define which `name` is it in this case? one of the two added input has `['name']` and the other is `['age']`

Comment: You can either write code so you know what the name is, do a string operation to extract the name, or you could do a find and replace on just the number. The find and replace is probably the easiest, I'll update my answer with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply change the string. To add the name `name` to the end of the `name` list before the `<br>`, you need to select each group separately and then use `after()` instead of `appendTo()`:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var names = $('#inputs').children('[name^="input[\'name"]');
  var clone = names.first().clone();
  clone.attr("name", "input['name'][" + (names.length + 1) + "]");
  names.last().after(clone);
  
  var ages = $('#inputs').children('[name^="input[\'age"]');
  clone = ages.first().clone();
  clone.attr("name", "input['age'][" + (ages.length + 1) + "]");
  ages.last().after(clone);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='inputs'>
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][1]">
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][2]">
  <input type='text' name="input['name'][3]">
  <hr>
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][1]">
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][2]">
  <input type='text' name="input['age'][3]">
</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

Note: I changed your `<br>` to `<hr>` only for demo so we can see it.